# Hangfire: JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'Role' with type 'Shared.Models.Role'. Path 'Roles[1].Users[0]'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, blazor, hangfire, json-serialization

I'm trying to create a backgroud job in the Api controller of my Blazor wasm App.
It start a simulation as background job.
The simulation method is a extension method of the database context.
Exception happens on `BackgroundJob.Enqueue()` line.

API end point below:

```
[HttpPost("CreateTask")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateTask(TaskCreateViewModel taskCreate)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    var task = new Shared.Models.ApplicationTask
    {
        UserId = taskCreate.UserId,
        ApplicationId = taskCreate.ApplicationId,
        Status = Status.CREATED.ToString(),
        Parameters = taskCreate.Parameters,
        Remarks = JsonSerializer.Serialize(taskCreate.Remarks),
        GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        FinishedFiles = ""
    };

    DbContext.Add(task);
    DbContext.SaveChanges();

    BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => DbContext.Run(taskCreate.Remarks,
                                                task.GUID,
                                                taskCreate.Parameters));

    return Ok(ModelState);
}
```

The extension end point below:

```
public static async Task Run(this ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext,
                                Dictionary<FileType, string> remarks,
                                string guid,
                                string parameter)
{
 
    var task = applicationDbContext
        .Tasks
        .First(t => t.GUID == guid);

    task.Status = Status.ANALYSING.ToString();
    task.Start = DateTime.Now;

    applicationDbContext.Update(task);

    var appId = applicationDbContext.Applications
        .Where(a => a.FacultyId == task.ApplicationId)
        .Select(x => x.Id)
        .First();

    var result = await Runner.Runner
        .Apps[appId]
        .Run(resources: remarks, parameters: parameter);

    var task2 = applicationDbContext.Tasks
        .First(t => t.GUID == guid);

    task2.Status = result.Status.ToString();
    task2.End = result.End;
    task2.FinishedFiles = result.ResultsSimulation.ToList().Serialize();

    applicationDbContext.Update(task2);

    applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Please include your 'Shared.Models.Role' class and your 'Shared.Models.User' class in your post. I suspect know the issue, but need more details to be sure

Comment: Its because you cant give the whole database to the hangfire, it creates all kinds of self reference errors, i solved it in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

you can ignore it.

```
services.AddHangfire((sp, config) =>
{
        //Add the line below
        config.UseSerializerSettings(new JsonSerializerSettings() { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
});
```